# API responding with HTML document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch, response

I created a brand new React app which uses "fetch" to retrieve some data from an API.

In my "App.js" file, within my App component, this can be seen.

```
 function getData() {
    fetch(`WORKINGURLWITHAPIKEY`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
  }
      
getData()
```

In the console I then receive the notorious
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" error`

I've tried everything including setting the headers, changing request methods, etc. I tested if the URL was valid and it was. I plugged it into the URL of the web browser and received back my desired data.

After doing a lot of research, I then looked at the actual response that I was receiving from my fetch request through Chrome DevTools and found out what was being sent back. The response was my React App's `index.html` template.

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: you're probably using the wrong URL in the request ... if it's an external (not yours) API, does the URL start with `http://` or `https://` or `//` - if not, the request is being made to your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to reach a different domain? If you are, `fetch` would require the URL to start with `http://`, but your browser would not.

Comment: I stupidly did not have https:// before my URL and adding it fixed everything, thank you very much!